# Installing Ubuntu on 32 bit pc

Tags: wireless

I have an old compaq presario 32 bit laptop which previously had mx linux installed originally windows vista, I now want to use Ubuntu and have wifi access, please can you advise the best download and how to install wireless...thank you

Comment: What is the CPU in your laptop? Maybe 64-bit will do as well.

Comment: Recent Ubuntu versions may not work well with a very old computer. You can use a slightly older version of flavoured Ubuntu like Xubuntu or Lubuntu 16.04 or 18.04, or stick to lighter operating systems like MX or Antix

Comment: I have 20.04 64 bit Kubuntu on my 2006 Toshiba laptop that I purchased just before Vista. Had Vista Ready sticker but was XP. Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors  Kubuntu is a bit slow, but works. Essentially retired laptop, and only for emergency use as battery is not charging. Other systems are all Kubuntu, so want familiar system.

Comment: If you're truly aiming to stay in the Ubuntu official flavors, Lubuntu is probably the lightest. Assuming you're correct and that you need a 32 bit OS, then that leaves you with 18.04 - which, sadly, will be running out of support soon. To be frank, you should probably be looking for other lightweight 32 bit distros. Have a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_Linux_distribution).

Comment: You gave no specs for your box, but I used devices as old as 2003 manufacture to test Lubuntu releases up to 19.04 (i386 pentium-M, pentium 4), though only 18.04 LTS is still supported, and yes Lubuntu was lightest as @KGIII said (I tested Xubuntu too; but it gets heavier as it ported to GTK3 just like MATE did... - but lightest for you will depend on your end use-case, and software you intend to use on it; if it's GTK3 you don't save little with a GTK2 desktop).

Comment: Also note:  on really early pentium M laptops (ibm thinkpad r50p, maybe t42p as well) required the use of `forcepae --forcepae` due to bugs inside the pentium M processor. It's not an issue with later pentium Ms (early pentium Ms report they are not PAE compatible which is needed; intel fixed only via microcode loaded after/as OS is booted (`initrd`) meaning boot issue remains forever unless forcepae is used) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE